# Correct usage of "which in turn"?

Tags: phrase-usage

I want to convey that affective strategy influences prior knowledge and also influences how much effort is exerted to acquire prior knowledge. Prior knowledge and effort exerted, in turn, affect the performance. Does the below sentence convey the same?

> Affective strategy positively influences students in acquiring prior
>   knowledge and exerting effort to acquire the later, which in turn
>   significantly affects the first-semester performance in engineering

Answer (score 1):

Affective strategy positively influences students in acquiring prior knowledge and exerting effort to acquire the later, which in turn significantly affects the first-semester performance in engineering

Edited:
Affective strategy positively influences students in acquiring knowledge and exerting efforts to do so, which, in turn, significantly affects their first-semester performance in engineering.

Please note: One does not "acquire prior knowledge". You can have prior knowledge of something, such as, for instance, a crime, but engineering students acquire knowledge, not prior knowledge.

the use of **which in turn** requires the use of commas.

Comment: Like many other constructions, I'd commatize *in turn* in a more complex sentence; but not here.

Comment: Well, I would keep at least an arm's length distance from your main verb.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with the sentence you propose, but your use of "in turn" is correct. First, in content; you are stating that effort to acquire *prior* knowledge has significant benefits beyond possessing that knowledge. This is not necessarily incorrect, but it seems possible you meant something different. In a similar vein, the compound direct object of the first clause is "acquiring prior knowledge" and "effort exerted to acquire the latter." Here "the latter" references "acquiring prior knowledge," so the second direct object is "effort exerted to acquire acquiring additional knowledge." Again, a valid sentence, but probably not what you intended. This could be resolved as follows:

> Affective strategy positively influences students in acquiring prior knowledge and exerting effort to do so,

Second, the first word in the sentence, "affective," may be incorrect. This word is rarely used outside of technical pulications in a few fields. You might mean effective, which means "having or producing an effect" Effect is a noun; an effect is something that occurs as a result of something else. In normal use, affect is a verb; one thing *affects* another, producing an effect. In addition, as others have pointed out, "latter" has two t's; later is a completely unrelated word.

Finally, your use of "affects" is incorrect. Because the subject is compound (effort and knowledge), the verb should have be "affect."

Those issues aside, your use of "in turn" is fine; the subject of this clause ("which," meaning prior knowledge and the effort to squire it) displays similar behavior to the subject of the previous clause (effective strategy), where this subject was the direct object.

Based on these problems, you might change your sentence to:

> Effective strategy positively influences students in acquiring prior knowledge and exerting effort to do so, which in turn significantly affect the first-semester performance in engineering.

Comment: "**affective strategies**" are *learning strategies concerned with managing emotions, both negative and positive. The relationship between affective strategies and learning is not clear, but a positive affective environment helps learning in general.* (Google search - first hit)

Comment: "affect" is a noun of technical use in psychology and psychotherapy, referring to emotions and their display, but it is hard to see how that was intended here. I have rarely seen it used outside of technical or semi-technical  publications on one of these subjects